# C# HttpWebRequest of type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" - how to send '&' character in content body?

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I'm writing a small API-connected application in C#.

I connect to a API which has a method that takes a long string, the contents of a calendar(ics) file.

I'm doing it like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.CookieContainer = my_cookie_container;
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

string iCalStr = GetCalendarAsString();

string strNew = "&uploadfile=true&file=" + iCalStr;

using (StreamWriter stOut = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
 {
     stOut.Write(strNew);
     stOut.Close();
 }
```

This seems to work great, until I add some specific HTML in my calendar.

If I have a '&nbsp' somewhere in my calendar (or similar) the server only gets all the data up to the '&'-point, so I'm assuming the '&' makes it look like anything after this point belongs to a new parameter?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Encode the string before sending it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since your content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you'll need to encode the POST body, especially if it contains characters like `&` which have special meaning in a form.

Try passing your string through [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) before writing it to the request stream.

Here are a couple links for reference.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: The second link goes to some Japanese site!

Comment: Thank you! For me I just had to convert my string strCallString = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strCallString) before posting it with .ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 59):

First install "[Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client)" nuget package:

```
  PM > Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
```

Then use the following function to post your data:

```
public static async Task<TResult> PostFormUrlEncoded<TResult>(string url, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData))
        {
            content.Headers.Clear();
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResult>();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
TokenResponse tokenResponse = 
    await PostFormUrlEncoded<TokenResponse>(OAuth2Url, OAuth2PostData);
```

or

```
TokenResponse tokenResponse = 
    (Task.Run(async () 
        => await PostFormUrlEncoded<TokenResponse>(OAuth2Url, OAuth2PostData)))
        .Result
```

or (not recommended)

```
TokenResponse tokenResponse = 
    PostFormUrlEncoded<TokenResponse>(OAuth2Url, OAuth2PostData).Result;
```

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but this way the request hangs

Comment: What is `OAuth2PostData` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet - When you post a request with `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it usually required some data. I copied the sample code from a code that was written for OAuth2 authentication so the varible name is `OAuth2PostData`. The name is not important, it is simply a variable that holds data. It is basically a list of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Comment: Sorry but how to use `TokenResponse` class? Add `using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;` ?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach - `TokenResponse` is your model. Define a class that matches the return schema of the Web API which you are calling. It is a simple POCO.

Answer (score 10):

As long as the server allows the ampresand character to be POSTed (not all do as it can be unsafe), all you should have to do is URL Encode the character. In the case of an ampresand, you should replace the character with `%26`.

.NET provides a nice way of encoding the entire string for you though:

```
string strNew = "&uploadfile=true&file=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(iCalStr);
```