# Binding JSON when POSTed with x-www-form-urlencoded not application/json

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to get the `DefaultModelBinder` to work when the data is POSTed using `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`, but the actual payload of the value is JSON encoded?

For example, I am being sent a single key-value-pair:

```
key: 'events' 
value: '[{"event":"inbound","ts":1350928095,"msg":{"raw_msg":"Received"}}]'
```

where the value contains JSON array in this case.

**NOTE: The POST is coming from a 3rd party so I cannot control it.**

Comment: I would've changed it myself, but there is a minimum amount of characters you need to change before it is an accepted edit. I didn't want to reword your question just to satisfy my OCD more quickly ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is "Sure.  Just use 'NAME=VALUE' (e.g. 'data=MYJSON'), and don't forget to encode before you send."

Here's an example:

- [C# HttpWebRequest of type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" - how to send '&' character in content body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665558/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-of-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-how-to-send)

But, re-reading your question, you're using MVC4.  That might impose restrictions over a simple C# or Java program :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You can either change the client to post application/json content type or write a custom model binder.

Answer (score 0):

*If you need this behavior in a single action* use the `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize the JSON content into a collection and validate the collection using `UpdateModel`/`TryUpdateModel` methods.

*If you need in many actions* then you have to go for a custom model binder by inheriting the `DefaultModelBinder` and override the `CreateModel` method. In the `CreateModel` method use the `JavaScriptSerializer` to create the objects from the POSTed value.

```
public class CustomModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
   protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
  {
     // JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     // return serializer.DeserializeObject(read the value from request);
  }
}
```

Now you can reuse the `CustomModelBinder` across actions using the `Bind` attribute.