# Proper way constructing a POST body data in Application/x-www-form-urlencoded using C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

How do i properly construct this data to use it as a BODY to perform a POST method request using HttpWebRequest

__EVENTARGUMENT:(empty),
__EVENTTARGET:ctl01$wseppPager$rptPageNumbers$ctl01$lbtnPageNumber,
__VIEWSTATE:(long string),
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:B4380F01,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl00$hfSkuId:bd665324-6f04-40b3-8a54-af0900c0dfb2,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl01$hfSkuId:b177f5bc-2aed-4ab1-8e36-af0200eac102,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl02$hfSkuId:108b6a02-2011-45b6-a09c-af010094004e,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl03$hfSkuId:a9db4d78-f277-449b-acc2-af0100962f8a,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl04$hfSkuId:388194aa-3574-4127-b09b-af010097cfb2,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl05$hfSkuId:959b14cc-b231-47ae-9fc9-aef300a3ed8c,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl06$hfSkuId:b4136acd-e84b-465a-9349-aef301235fcc,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl07$hfSkuId:e058bb2c-328a-46d3-93c3-aef3012d3cbb,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl08$hfSkuId beda3ab2-c21b-4e75-b4df-aeb0008d8b15,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl09$hfSkuId:8c5ffafc-175c-43d1-8302-ae66012cfbfb,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl10$hfSkuId:dce89988-e6d3-4154-b0d3-ae4a012e2475,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl11$hfSkuId:554a1bbf-bd67-4364-ac8e-ae4a012f07ac,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl12$hfSkuId:912c3feb-98aa-4499-8e7f-ae4a01300aea,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl13$hfSkuId:c4574ed3-af2a-4845-b283-ae3900c7c23d,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl14$hfSkuId:88089ed1-41d2-453f-94b3-ae3900c2046d,
ctl01$rptProducts$ctl15$hfSkuId:8535c21f-ba48-4c4d-bcc8-ae220113f0f7,
ctl01$wseppSorter$ddlPageSize:16,
ctl01$wseppSorter$ddlSortBy:CreatedDate Descending,

This is my code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
request.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua", @"""Google Chrome"";v=""105"", ""Not)A;Brand"";v=""8"", ""Chromium"";v=""105""");
request.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", @"?0");
request.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", @"""Windows""");
request.Headers.Add("Origin", @"https://www.pny.com");
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
request.Headers.Add("DNT", @"1");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";
request.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", @"same-origin");
request.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", @"navigate");
request.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", @"?1");
request.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", @"document");
request.Referer = "...";
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.9");
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, @Cookies);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

byte[] postBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@Body);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
```

i've already tried this but its not working.

Edit:

i tried adding it into a List of Key Value pair like this.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
Body.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__EVENTTARGET", "ctl01$wseppPager$lbtnNextPage"));
```

and parsing the body to

```
string body_kvp_encoded = string.Join("&", Body.Select(kvp => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));
string body_not_encoded = string.Join("&", Body.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}"));
```

but still not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# HttpWebRequest of type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" - how to send '&' character in content body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665558/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-of-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-how-to-send)

Comment: You will also need to "encode" the data. using HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Comment: i will try it on my end, thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax you mean the entire body not just the key value pair?.

just like this?

string body_urlencoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Join("&", Body.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}")), Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: You string data contains special character so encode using : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)

Comment: @JAKE The entire body of the request needs to be encoded, the clue is the content-type ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, @Cookies);
```

replace it with

```
request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
```

UrlEncode Key and value Pair

```
string body_kvp_encoded = string.Join("&", Body.Select(kvp => $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));
```

Thank you guys